# Normal Difference Distribution Median and Variance non-commutative

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I am trying to understand how to relate the variance of a population of measurements that were previously calculated with the Normal Difference Distribution, but I am needing to change the actual steps.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html

In this case the variance is the convolution of the individual variances of X and Y.

In the case where I need to move to, I need to subtract X and Y first, then look at the mean and variance of the population.

Is this really as simple as just calculating the variance of (x-y) for the population?

The easiest example I can find to ask from would be similar to dithering on this page, where slightly shifted frames are subtracted from each other as opposed to stacking everything and then subtracting.
https://astrobackyard.com/how-to-take-dark-frames/

I realize there are other methods of doing the above- but I'm looking for help on the math, not the method.

Comment: The variance of the difference there is simply the direct *sum* of the variances ($\sigma^2_x + \sigma^2_y$), not the "convolution of the individual variances"  ($\sigma^2_x \circledast \sigma^2_y$) -- except in the trivial sense of placing a point mass at the population parameters so that the convolution is just the sum, which seems rather an unnecessary complication on a simple notion

Comment: Thank you. Given that this subtraction operation happens before the measurement of variance, it would seem then to have no impact to the current method of adding the variances. That's what the formulas say and I still would have expected it to be different, but I can run a simulation or so to see. Thank you for helping me see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the difference scores, then yes, you can estimate the variance of the difference directly from the observed differences.

Indeed this has the advantage of avoiding assumptions about the correlation between them, so if the differences are readily available, this is not only okay, I'd say its advisable.

Comment: Thank you. So once again I'm making things too difficult. Story of my life lately :)